# PHP & API for IP Geolocation

Tags: php, mysql, api, geolocation

I am trying to use http://www.hostip.info/use.html in my web app to show the approximate City location of an IP address. I cannot figure out how to actually show the contents of the API... Here is what I have that is not working.

```
function showCity($currIP){

$lookupData = 'http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip='.$currIP;
return $lookupData;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your API returns this:

```
Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: Seattle, WA
IP: 168.111.127.225
```

So you need to do some string parsing on that result.  Using the below will get your started:

```
 $array = preg_split('/$\R?^:/m', $lookupData);
 print_r($array);
```

Try this instead:

```
$array = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", $lookupData, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Also, as was mentioned by mcmajkel, if you use the JSON api link, you can get to it with this:

```
$lookupData = 'http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip='.$currIP;
$api = json_decode($lookupData);
$myName = $api->country_name;
$myCode = $api->country_code;
$myCity = $api->city;
$myIP   = $api->ip;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I get this:
Array ( [0] => http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx )

Comment: Adjusted answer with new regex - give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This call returns string, as mentioned by GregP. But you can call
http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=12.215.42.19

And get a nice piece of JSON in return, which will be easier to
[parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)